# How to test that a route does not exist in Rails 4.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a route **not** defined, how do I test that it returns a 404?

Here is the relevant part of routes.rb

```
resources :reservations, only: [:index,:create,:destroy]
```

You can create, destroy and list reservations, but not change them.

The test then is:

```
patch :update, id: @reservation, reservation: { somefield: "data" }
assert_response :missing
```

This should pass, since the lack of a route should return a 404. Instead, I get a UrlGenerationError:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"reservations", :id=>"980190962", :reservation=>{:somefield=>"data"}}
```

I get it; the `patch` call from the test cannot generate a URL. So how do I test that such a URL call would generate a 404?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually could assert an error like this has been thrown, would it be sufficient for you?

```
assert_raise ActionController::UrlGenerationError do
  patch :update, id: @reservation, reservation: { somefield: "data" }
end
```

Comment: Is that a real test? It would be exercising the `patch` call, and not the routes. Well, I guess it would work. I will use it for now, but wait and see if there is a different way.

Comment: @deitch well, another way, that comes to my mind is to use `Net::HTTP` library and use it like `Net::HTTP::Patch.new(url) ...` and then check if result is of type `Net::HTTPNotFound`... didn't test this myself, though

Comment: No, I thought about it, and your original answer is right. using `patch :update` *means* "create a URL based on the route to patch", which, if the route doesn't exist, should raise the `UrlGenerationError`. It is precisely the right test.